# Create a new column based on vectors pre-determined using case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, case, grouping, mutate

I have a large data.frame called "`sim`" that has a character column named "`CAUSABAS`", something like this:

```
CAUSABAS OBITOGRAV OBITOPARTO   OBITOPUERP  ANO idade      idade_dias 
1     I110      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2013 95.58      34909  
2     C349      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2013 80.70      29474 
3     C490      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2013 97.90      35757 
4     I219      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2013 87.60      31995 
5     I259      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2013 62.57      22853 
6     I678      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2013 51.99      18988
```

This data.frame is created using the package `microdatasus`, like that:

```
sim_mg <- fetch_datasus(year_start = 2013, year_end = 2018,
                        information_system = "SIM-DO",
                        uf = "MG")
sim_es <- fetch_datasus(year_start = 2013, year_end = 2018,
                        information_system = "SIM-DO",
                        uf = "ES")
sim <- bind_rows(sim_es, sim_mg) %>%
  select(TIPOBITO, DTOBITO, DTNASC, CODMUNOCOR, CODMUNRES, TPMORTEOCO, TPOBITOCOR, LINHAA, LINHAB, LINHAC, LINHAD, LINHAII, CAUSABAS, OBITOGRAV, OBITOPARTO, OBITOPUERP) %>%
  mutate(ANO = substr(DTOBITO, 5, 8))
sim$CAUSABAS <- unfactor(sim$CAUSABAS)
```

I want to create the following column: `grupo_causa_basica`, that classifies these `CAUSABAS`.

Some of the observation has 3 strings, like `B50`, but another has 4, like `B501`.

The group of `B50` has, for example, 3 other `CAUSABAS`, `B500`, `B508` and `B509`. Sometimes the input is `B50`, but not always. All the observations follow this kind of organization.

I've created some vectors to specify what is what:

```
doen_cardio <- c("F01","G45","G46","I10","I11","I13","I15","I21","I22","I23","I24","I25",
                 "I26","I27","I28","I37","I49","I50","I51","I52","I63","I64","I67","I68",
                 "I69","I71","I72","I73","I80","K55","O10","O16","P29","P60","R931","R943")
diabetes <- c("E10","E11","E12","E13","E14","O24","P70")
doencas_respiratorias <- c("R91","R942","J06","J16","J20","J21","J22","J30","J31","J34",
                           "J40","J41","J42","J45","J46","J60","J61","J62","J63","J64",
                           "J66","J67","J68","J69","J70","J80","J81","J82","J84","J96",
                           "J98","J99","P22","P26","P27","P28","R04","R06","R09","R84",
                           "T17","W77","W83","W84")
doen_renais <- c("R934","R944","E27","I12","N07","N17","N18","N19","N25","N27","Q60")
intox_exogenas <- c("T45","T46","T47","T48","T57","T61","T62","T65","T97","X47","X49",
                    "Y13","Y17","Y19")
doen_infec_veic_hidrica <- c("A01","A02","A03","A04","A05","A06","A07","A08","A09","A27",
                             "B15","B58","B65","B77","R10","A00","B68","B69","B76","B80",
                             "B82","B89","N220")
arbov <- c("A92","P354","A90","A91","A95","B50","B51","B52","B53","B54")
doen_pele <- c("R23","L08","L98","L99")
```

After that I tried to use `mutate` plus `case_when`:

```
sim <- sim %>%
   mutate(grupo_causa_basica = case_when(CAUSABAS %in% doen_cardio ~ "cardio",
                                         CAUSABAS %in% diabetes ~ "diabetes",
                                         CAUSABAS %in% doencas_respiratorias ~ "doen_resp",
                                         CAUSABAS %in% doen_renais ~ "doen_renais",
                                         CAUSABAS %in% intox_exogenas ~ "intox_exogenas",
                                         CAUSABAS %in% doen_infec_veic_hidrica ~ "doen_infec_veic_hidrica",
                                         CAUSABAS %in% arbov ~ "arbov",
                                         CAUSABAS %in% doen_pele ~ "doen_pele"))
```

These worked, however, my code forgot about the cases like `B500`, `B508`, `B509`. As I specified in the vector "`arbov`" only `B50`, it only classified `B50`, not `B500` or `B508`.

In that way, I was wondering that I had to do something with the vectors: take all strings in the vectors that starts with these specifications. So I realized that I could use `startsWith`:

```
sim <- sim %>%
  mutate(grupo_causa_basica = case_when(startsWith(CAUSABAS, doen_cardio) ~ "cardio",
                                        startsWith(CAUSABAS, diabetes) ~ "diabetes",
                                        startsWith(CAUSABAS, doencas_respiratorias) ~ "doen_resp",
                                        startsWith(CAUSABAS, doen_renais) ~ "doen_renais",
                                        startsWith(CAUSABAS, intox_exogenas) ~ "intox_exogenas",
                                        startsWith(CAUSABAS, doen_infec_veic_hidrica) ~ "doen_infec_veic_hidrica",
                                        startsWith(CAUSABAS, arbov) ~ "arbov",
                                        startsWith(CAUSABAS, doen_pele) ~ "doen_pele"))
```

However, it was not the desirable solution. When I table the first try, it gives me something like:

```
table(sim$grupo_causa_basica)

                  arbov                  cardio doen_infec_veic_hidrica             doen_renais               doen_resp 
                    638                   51087                    2514                    2614                    2895
```

and when I table the second try, it brings me that:

```
 table(sim$grupo_causa_basica)

                  arbov                  cardio                diabetes doen_infec_veic_hidrica               doen_pele 
                    103                    5650                    5445                     173                     254 
            doen_renais               doen_resp          intox_exogenas 
                   1371                     656                      17
```

How can I do that considering all the strings that initiate with the specified in the vectors?

Comment: What if before your first try using `case_when()` you did `mutate(CAUSABAS = str_sub(CAUSABAS, 1, 3)`, which would just keep the first three characters, then you could match them to the existing three-character designations.

Comment: the problem is that in some vectors, for example doen_cardio, i need the CAUSABAS R931 and R943, which has 4 strings

Comment: So, how do you know when to match the first three values and when to only match all four values?

Comment: in the cases that I have to match 4 values, I have specified

Answer (score 0):

The API timed out when I tried to use the data downloading functions, but what about something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(stringr)
doen_cardio <- c("F01","G45","G46","I10","I11","I13","I15","I21","I22","I23","I24","I25",
                 "I26","I27","I28","I37","I49","I50","I51","I52","I63","I64","I67","I68",
                 "I69","I71","I72","I73","I80","K55","O10","O16","P29","P60","R931","R943")
diabetes <- c("E10","E11","E12","E13","E14","O24","P70")
doencas_respiratorias <- c("R91","R942","J06","J16","J20","J21","J22","J30","J31","J34",
                           "J40","J41","J42","J45","J46","J60","J61","J62","J63","J64",
                           "J66","J67","J68","J69","J70","J80","J81","J82","J84","J96",
                           "J98","J99","P22","P26","P27","P28","R04","R06","R09","R84",
                           "T17","W77","W83","W84")
doen_renais <- c("R934","R944","E27","I12","N07","N17","N18","N19","N25","N27","Q60")
intox_exogenas <- c("T45","T46","T47","T48","T57","T61","T62","T65","T97","X47","X49",
                    "Y13","Y17","Y19")
doen_infec_veic_hidrica <- c("A01","A02","A03","A04","A05","A06","A07","A08","A09","A27",
                             "B15","B58","B65","B77","R10","A00","B68","B69","B76","B80",
                             "B82","B89","N220")
arbov <- c("A92","P354","A90","A91","A95","B50","B51","B52","B53","B54")
doen_pele <- c("R23","L08","L98","L99")

doen_cardio <- ifelse(nchar(doen_cardio) == 3, paste0(doen_cardio, ".*"), doen_cardio)
diabetes <- ifelse(nchar(diabetes) == 3, paste0(diabetes, ".*"), diabetes)
doencas_respiratorias <- ifelse(nchar(doencas_respiratorias) == 3, paste0(doencas_respiratorias, ".*"), doencas_respiratorias)
doen_renais <- ifelse(nchar(doen_renais) == 3, paste0(doen_renais, ".*"), doen_renais)
intox_exogenas <- ifelse(nchar(intox_exogenas) == 3, paste0(intox_exogenas, ".*"), intox_exogenas)
doen_infec_veic_hidrica <- ifelse(nchar(doen_infec_veic_hidrica) == 3, paste0(doen_infec_veic_hidrica, ".*"), doen_infec_veic_hidrica)
arbov <- ifelse(nchar(arbov) == 3, paste0(arbov, ".*"), arbov)
doen_pele <- ifelse(nchar(doen_pele) == 3, paste0(doen_pele, ".*"), doen_pele)

doen_cardio <- paste(doen_cardio, collapse="|")
diabetes <- paste(diabetes, collapse="|")
doencas_respiratorias <- paste(doencas_respiratorias, collapse="|")
doen_renais <- paste(doen_renais, collapse="|")
intox_exogenas <- paste(intox_exogenas, collapse="|")
doen_infec_veic_hidrica <- paste(doen_infec_veic_hidrica, collapse="|")
arbov <- paste(arbov, collapse="|")
doen_pele <- paste(doen_pele, collapse="|")

tib <- tibble::tribble(
  ~CAUSABAS, ~OBITOGRAV, ~OBITOPARTO,   ~OBITOPUERP,  ~ANO, ~idade,      ~idade_dias, 
"I110",      NA,       NA,       NA, 2013, 95.58,      34909,  
"C349",      NA,       NA,       NA, 2013, 80.70,      29474, 
"C490",      NA,       NA,       NA, 2013, 97.90,      35757, 
"I219",      NA,       NA,       NA, 2013, 87.60,      31995, 
"I259",      NA,       NA,       NA, 2013, 62.57,      22853, 
"I678",      NA,       NA,       NA, 2013, 51.99,      18988)


tib %>% 
  mutate(grupo_causa_basica = case_when(str_detect(CAUSABAS, doen_cardio) ~ "cardio",
                                        str_detect(CAUSABAS, diabetes) ~ "diabetes",
                                        str_detect(CAUSABAS, doencas_respiratorias) ~ "doen_resp",
                                        str_detect(CAUSABAS, doen_renais) ~ "doen_renais",
                                        str_detect(CAUSABAS, intox_exogenas) ~ "intox_exogenas",
                                        str_detect(CAUSABAS, doen_infec_veic_hidrica) ~ "doen_infec_veic_hidrica",
                                        str_detect(CAUSABAS, arbov) ~ "arbov",
                                        str_detect(CAUSABAS, doen_pele) ~ "doen_pele"))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 8
#>   CAUSABAS OBITOGRAV OBITOPARTO OBITOPUERP   ANO idade idade_dias grupo_causa_…¹
#>   <chr>    <lgl>     <lgl>      <lgl>      <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>         
#> 1 I110     NA        NA         NA          2013  95.6      34909 cardio        
#> 2 C349     NA        NA         NA          2013  80.7      29474 <NA>          
#> 3 C490     NA        NA         NA          2013  97.9      35757 <NA>          
#> 4 I219     NA        NA         NA          2013  87.6      31995 cardio        
#> 5 I259     NA        NA         NA          2013  62.6      22853 cardio        
#> 6 I678     NA        NA         NA          2013  52.0      18988 cardio        
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​grupo_causa_basica
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>